# Groups delta query does not return members when specified in $select

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm integrating with Azure AD using the Microsoft Graph API v1.0. I'm fetching the groups using delta query with specifying the `members` property  in the `$select` query parameter, along with some other properties as our integration does not use most of Azure AD group properties.

This used to work, however currently when performing the same query the members are not returned from the endpoint. If I don't specify the `$select` then the members are returned, along with many other group properties.

When digging around with the endpoint I've noticed that I can get the members using the $expand query parameter. Is this the correct way of asking for members to be included in the results of a delta query?

For reference this is how the query that no longer works looks like:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$select=displayName,id,members
```

Comment: $Select should return members. Was it working with Microsoft Graph API beta version and not working with v1? Can you share the query that you are using (You can substitute <id> for personal data)?

Comment: It used to work, I no longer get the same responses that I used to despite using the same query. The API version I'm using is v1.0. I've added the URL I'm making requests to in the original question. The members attribute is ignored if it's in $select, but works if it's in $expand. I don't know if it worked with $expand before, but it definitely did with $select

Comment: We have identified the cause of the issue and are working on the fix.

Comment: @DavidHou if that's the case then that would be great, are both forms valid by the way? We're currently including the parameter both in $select and $expand, as I wasn't sure if $expand was valid before and specifying it in both is more defensive in case if the API starts only accepting members in $select

Comment: @DavidHou We urgently need an update on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that this issue has actually been resolved by the Microsoft Graph team. Thank you for bringing this to our attention! Apologies that we never got back to you on this.